# When using the shared slot pool for a batch load, is it possible to see how many slots were used in the load job?

Tags: google-bigquery, data-warehouse

I am using the free trial from Google Big Query to test the DWH and compare it to the other big DWH's (Azure, Redshift, Snowflake). For that I made a test dataset with 100 files and loaded it into my Big Query DWH. After loading the data I can see a things like id, startingtime, endtime, etc... in the job details. But I cannot find an information about the amount of used slots for the load. Is it possible to find the information somewhere in the UI or the information_schema?

I already tried looking in the job history and the information schema, but couldn't find anything about the amount of used slots for the Load job.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.